# difference between LoadedpivotItem and LoadingPivotItem

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot, windows-phone-7.1

What is difference between LoadedpivotItem and LoadingPivotItem ? Or there is any link where u can get all the pivot Events documentation ?

Answer (score 3):

here you can read all about PivotItem controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941123(v=vs.92).aspx

Loaded means that the control has finished wiht loading.

Loading means you can manipulate the content before it is displayed.

Hope this helps.